# (How) can I build multi-file projects on Compiler Explorer with MSVC?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, makefile, compiler-explorer

[This](https://godbolt.org/z/WseTsM8YG) is the link that [Matt Godbolt posted on reddit a year ago or so](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/pcrg7j/compiler_explorer_now_supports_multiple_file/): a multifile project compliled by his Compiler Explorer.

Clearly, as soon as I change the compiler to MSVC, the building [fails](https://godbolt.org/z/KcMePd44T); not just because of the options (e.g. `-std=c++17` should be `/std:c++17`), but mainly because of the makefile.

How do I need to alter the project to make it compile with MSVC?

Comment: As I know, make requires POSIX, I assume it is not Installed on the msvc servers. Try to use cmake instead.

Comment: @FabianKeßler, the example I linked does use cmake.

Comment: Then tell cmake to generate a VS Solution.

Comment: @sweenish, I've tried replicating the first, small, one-file, example [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/), but [it looks like Compiler Explorer is interpreting `CMakeLists.txt` as it was a C++ TU](https://godbolt.org/z/Kfxfbjv8a).

Comment: I found this comment in [github](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/discussions/2763#discussioncomment-1393814). It seems that it still applies for now..

Comment: And [this](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/3216#issuecomment-1002099027) for more details.